# TideSDK with Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc, tidesdk

Just wondering, is it possible to turn spring mvc web development content into a desktop application using TideSDK? Both are using HTML5 as the front-end. Then, as for the back-end process, it should be able to reuse the java code inside spring mvc.

I just finish a web project that was developed using spring mvc, and there is a request to turn it into a desktop application. I was looking around and found that you can use HTML5 for creating desktop application. It would be nice if I can directly convert it to desktop.

Thanks for the response :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. TideSDK has support for different server languages, such as PHP and Python, but Java is not one of them.

What you could try is to make the app a shell for the webpage. So when the app starts it immediately loads http://yoururl.com, the behavior would be exactly the same as in a webbrowser.

Comment: I did notice that TideSDK only support a few languages but dont think that it would be a problem with Java though. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you load any remote URL, all native functionality would not be available to the page.

Comment: Hmm..than that would be a problem to me. Thanks for the input :D